# How to allow only email as username alias with CloudFormation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cognito

Following [this guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/getting-started.html), it says:

> On the Attributes tab, select Email address or phone number and select Allow email addresses.

Which looks like this:

[image]

But I'm having trouble accomplishing the same thing with CloudFormation. Tried a couple of the [obvious attributes](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-cognito-userpool.html#cfn-cognito-userpool-aliasattributes) but did not work. Thoughts?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's now possible to do this by setting the `UsernameAttributes` property to an array of strings containing either `email`, `phone_number` or both:

```
Type: AWS::Cognito::UserPool
Properties:
  UsernameAttributes:
  - "email"
  UserPoolName: "test-pool"
```

Comment: This worked but I couldn't find this in the docs; where did you learn about this?

Comment: @DMor I think I found a link on their forum that pointed to a beta version of the documentation that isn't yet published on the main site.

Answer (score 2):

Totally agree with [0x6C38](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2180290/0x6c38)

```
UserPool:
    Type: "AWS::Cognito::UserPool"
    Properties:
      UserPoolName: "test-pool"
      UsernameAttributes: [email]      
      AutoVerifiedAttributes:
        - email
```

Note! Only one of the aliasAttributes or usernameAttributes can be set in a User pool.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that not possible using CFN. See this thread:
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=259349&tstart=0

> Username attributes is a recently rolled out feature and it will be
>   added in cloudformation templates soon.